# how to insert update and delete records in tables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a large windows form with 50 different fields (text boxes,combo boxes,listview,check box) i have 10 tables in sql server database each table have  different column I want to insert my windows forms 50 fields in these 10 tables. Here is my code to insert record in a table

```
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
  cmd.Connection = conn
  cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into ChartOfAccount (MainCode,MainDescription,AccountCode,AccountDescription,OpeningBalance) values ('" & MainCode & "','" & MainDescription & "','" & AccountCode & "','" & AccountDescription & "','" & OpeningBalance & "')"
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

So question is if I insert data into 10 different tables then I need to write 10 insert statments.

If I update or delete record I need to write update and delete command 10 tables seprately
this will take long time please guide me if any short method exists.

Comment: You can use stored procedure.In store procedure,you can pass parameter and can write more than one sql statement.

Comment: do u have any example sangram

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is susceptible with SQL injection so better to use parameters:

```
        Dim connStr as String = "connection string values here";
        using con as new SqlConnection(connStr)

              Dim commandText as String = 
                 @"Insert Into ChartOfAccount (MainCode
                 ,MainDescription,AccountCode
                 ,AccountDescription,OpeningBalance) 
               VALUES 
               (@MainCode, @MainDesc,@AccountCode
               ,@AccountDesc,@OpeningBalance)"
              Dim cmd as New SqlCommand(commandText,con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainCode",MainCode)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainDesc",MainDescription)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountCode",AccountCode)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountDesc",AccountDescription)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpeningBalance",OpeningBalance)

            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex as Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 
            End Try
        End Using
```

Now, this is only for Inserting records example.

Comment: edper question is if  insert record to another table i need to write whole code again

Comment: First this is a self-contained code so it has the connection, command etc. However, if you are using a Class to do this specially in Layered enviroment like having a Data-Tier to do this - you may code every table in that Class/Layer but you could re-use it without having to code again. Say, DataTier.Insert("TableName",classForTable).

Comment: See a simple example on the link that follows http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET.

Comment: Here's more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786549/how-to-implement-3-tiers-architecture-in-c-sharp and this link also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332381.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure for that. In order to create a stored procedure, you can use the following SQL query:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[NewUser] 
@Yourparameter1 int , 
@Yourparamtere2
As
Insert into dbo.Users 
( 
 // Db columns 
 Column1 , 
 Column2 
) 
values 
( 
@Yourparameter1
@Yourparameter2
)
```

And in your C# code, create a `SQLParameter` collection and pass it to the procedure. It will work fine and smoothly, and this way your code will be simpler.

Comment: this store procedure insert record into users table when i insert record in a department table then i need to write another store procedure.and when i insert record in employee table then i need another store procudre and so on........ 10 times

Comment: Yes, but IF you use stored procedures that will simplicity your work, because you don't have to use sql querry in C# , instead you will just pass the name of the procedure and add parameters ,

Comment: so dooby i need to write 10 store procedure and then pass every table parameters seprately

Comment: No , You can add to as many as tables from one single procedure.