# Return false when I have Identical record in the database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want in case I have patient in the database with the same surname and DOB to return false. At the moment the code below return false event when I don't have duplication
Thanks

```
C# code
   private bool duplicatPatient()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();    
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT     MBID, HospitalNumber, NHSNumber, DOB, Surname, Forename
                            FROM         Patient
                             WHERE
                                    Surname= @Surname and DOB= @DOB";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSearchSurname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtSearchDOB.Text);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        int userCount = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        da.Fill(dt);
```

This section of the code check if we have more that one patient

```
        if (userCount >1 )
        {
          // message in case we have patient with same details 
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Details entered Return more than one Patient. Click Patient Information Link to Select the Right Patient')</script>");
            return false;

        }
        else
        {
             // no patient with same record
            return true;

        }

     }
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar() is used when your query returns single value. Why don't you use executequery instead. and change the condition userCount >1 .Put resulting records in datatable(dt) and check if recordcount is greater than 0. use it in if else condition.

Comment: Seeing "SqlConnection" in the same codeblock as "txtSearchSurname.Text" hurts my eyes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786549/how-to-implement-3-tiers-architecture-in-c-sharp

Comment: You also should be wrapping your connection and command objects in USING statements. And be careful with AddWithValue. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteScalar only return first column of first row of a query

You need to execute scalar on another query:

```
    cmdCount.CommandText = @"SELECT    count(*)
                        FROM         Patient
                         WHERE
                                Surname= @Surname and DOB= @DOB";

    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSearchSurname.Text);
    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtSearchDOB.Text);


    int cmdCount= (int) cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` which return the first column of the first row returned by the query which in you case its `MBID`.

You coul either use a `SELECT COUNT` type statement to count the returned rows or just use `cmd.ExecuteReader` and loop through the results keeping you select.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code acccordingly to

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT count(MBID)
                       FROM Patient
                      WHERE
                         Surname= @Surname and DOB= @DOB";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend your Sql query

try the following

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT  Count(*) 
                            FROM         Patient
                             WHERE
                                    Surname= @Surname and DOB= @DOB";
```

This should return a int with the number of matches.